# Build dict in loop. Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to find out what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm trying to build a simple ordered dict inside a loop.

Heres the code:

```
dTabs = OrderedDict()

for iFolder, folder in enumerate(mtd.GroupedTables):

    if folder.Count > 0:

        dTabs[folder.Name] = OrderedDict()

        for item in folder:

            table = item.Table

            dTabs[folder.Name] = table.Name

print dTabs
```

this is the output:

```
 OrderedDict([('YouthSportsTrustSportParents_P', 'KYS_Q8_YouthSportsTrustSportParents_P'), ('YouthSportsTrustSportParents_PM', 'KYS_Q8_YouthSportsTrustSportParents_PM')])
```

there should be six more values for each key...but im only seeing the last two values for each key.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You do `dTabs[folder.Name] = OrderedDict()` and later do `dTabs[folder.Name] = table.Name`. You're overwriting the `OrderedDict` with a string. Is that intentional?

Comment: No its not intentional, didnt know that was happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop assigns in the same location over and over

```
dTabs = OrderedDict()
for iFolder, folder in enumerate(mtd.GroupedTables):
    if folder.Count > 0:
        dTabs[folder.Name] = OrderedDict()
        for item in folder:
            table = item.Table
            dTabs[folder.Name] = table.Name # same location is being updated
print dTabs
```

you need a list like data structure to hold each "table.Name"

```
dTabs = OrderedDict()
for iFolder, folder in enumerate(mtd.GroupedTables):
    if folder.Count > 0:
        dTabs[folder.Name] = []
        for item in folder:
            table = item.Table
            dTabs[folder.Name].append(table.Name)
print dTabs
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner for loop:

```
    for item in folder:
        table = item.Table
        dTabs[folder.Name] = table.Name
```

overwrites the value of dTabs[folder.Name] each time it goes through-- that is, for each `item` in folder, `folder.Name` is the same, and each subsequent `item` overwrites the last one's entry because it has the same key! I think that you think that you can have more than one value per key, which is not true. Try appending onto the current value for the key, instead of replacing it.

Comment: I understand what your saying but how do I do that? I think the values need to be a list then?